# How to compose writeFile with Either data type?

Tags: haskell

I have a function that accepts some arguments and returns `IO (Either String String)`, say

```
testEither :: Int -> IO (Either String String)
testEither 0 = return (Left "we got an error")
testEither _ = return (Right "everything is ok")
```

(Real function fetches some stuff from real world and might fail)

I want to send output from that function to `writeFile fileName`. Expected behavior: if I bind `testEither 0` to `writeFile "test.txt"`, I fail with `Left ...`, and if I call it with `testEither 1`, I get `everything is ok` in file `test.txt`.

I guess the type of the whole expression should be something like `IO (Either String ())`, but I may be wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [ErrorT](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.2.0.1/docs/Control-Monad-Error.html)<sup>1</sup> monad transformer to give you pure error handling on top of the `IO` monad:

```
import Control.Monad.Error

testEither :: Int -> IO (Either String String)
testEither 0 = return (Left "we got an error")
testEither _ = return (Right "everything is ok")

main = runErrorT $ do
    result <- ErrorT $ testEither 0
    lift $ writeFile "test.txt" result
```

<sub><sup>1</sup> `ErrorT` appears to have been replaced with [`ExceptT`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl/docs/Control-Monad-Except.html) in the newest version of `mtl`, but the functionality should be similar.</sub>

Answer (score 4):

This is easy using `Either`'s `Traversable` instance:

```
import Data.Traversable

main = do
    traverse (writeFile "test.txt") (Left "we got an error")
    traverse (writeFile "test.txt") (Right "everything is ok")
```

Answer (score 2):

This won't happen automatically, but you can easily use pattern matching to perform this action:

```
writeFileEither :: FilePath -> Either a String -> IO ()
writeFileEither _  (Left _) = return ()
writeFileEither fp (Right text) = writeFile fp text
```

Then you can bind them together with

```
main = testEither 1 >>= writeFileEither "test.txt"
```

Or with do notation:

```
main = do
    result <- testEither 1
    writeFileEither "test.txt" result
```

Answer (score 1):

The `main` function below is an example that show how to use `testEither` in `IO`: if `testEither` returns an error then the error is written to `stderr` else the correct result is extracted from `Right` and written to the file `test.txt`:

```hs
import System.IO

testEither :: Int → IO (Either String String)
testEither 0 = return (Left "we got an error")
testEither _ = return (Right "everything is ok")

main :: IO 
main = do
  res ← testEither 0
  case res of
    Left err → hPutStrLn stderr ("Error: " ++ err)
    Right s  → writeFile "test.txt" s
```